# expand a div if the other doesn't exist

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two divs like below. one fixed width and the other should expand to the rest of available with.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #ads
    {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
    }
    #content-panel
    {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: both;">
    @if (Resources.Ads.ClassA == "true")
    {
        <div id="ads">
            <div>
                <img src="../../Content/img/Ads/xlpar.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div id="content-panel">
        @Html.Action("Elanat", "Home")
        @Html.Action("Latest", "AdsCatalog")
        <div class="article-wrapper">
            <div class="article-titlebar">
                <h4>
                    @Resources.CommonRes.WellcomeTitle</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="article-content">
                @Html.Raw(Resources.CommonRes.welcome)
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.Action("Latest", "News")
        @Html.Partial("VisitCounterDisplay")
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to check a value and if(true) Ads div should be displayed and content-div should be like the rest of the available with. and when if(false) the ad-div should not be displayed. and the content div must be with 100% width. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not add a class to the content-panel based on if there is an ad or not:

```
<div id="content-panel" class="@Html.Raw(Resources.Ads.ClassA == "true" ? "withAdd" : "withoutAdd")>
```

then you can just apply the relevant styles to the relevant classes

also if `Resources.Ads.ClassA` is a boolean you can just do `if (Resources.Ads.ClassA) {}`

Comment: Hey, what is this programming language which you are using here in HTML? just curious to know. (Looks like old asp to me)

Comment: it is html with Razor microsoft seem to be putting the code back into the html pages

Comment: thanks. i feel like an idiot. why it doesn't came up on my mind!!!!thanks bro. it was very helpfull